# Laravel 5.1 Auth::attempt() not working if User has softdelete attribute

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1, soft-delete

It's working if there is no softdelete attribute on User model. Here is my code:

User model:

```
.....
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $softDelete = true;
.....
```

AuthController:

```
........
$userdata = ['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => 1];
$authRemember = (Input::get('auth_remember'))? true : false;

// if (Auth::validate($userdata)) {
    if (Auth::attempt($userdata, $authRemember)) {
        echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
// }else{
//  echo 'failed';
// }
.....
```

I already set **deleted_at TIMESTAMP** and **active TINYINT** to my users table.
any help would be appreciated.

**Resolved**
it's worked after I set the default value to NULL for the `deleted_at` column and remove `'active' => 1` from the code above

Comment: Try `protected $softDelete = true;`

Comment: @aldrin27 already trying to add those code but still no luck

Comment: So it always return's false?

Comment: Yes, it always return false. I also have try to remove `if (Auth::validate($userdata)) {}` but still won't work

Comment: try to `return Input::all()` if all the data is there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's worked after I set the default value to NULL for the `deleted_at` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it not work if the User is softDeleted or even if the deleted_at is null? A bit more information will be great. Does an error occur?

And are you sure that the deleted_at is null? We had A similar problem and the solution was that we trimed all columns and that brings the deleted_at to A not empty value.

Comment: As I know, MySQL default for the empty column with TIMESTAMP format is  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Btw, would you tell me how to trim all columns?

Comment: Thanks @Gummibeer it's worked after I set the default value to NULL for the `deleted_at` column

Comment: Happy to hear! :) And yes I can - in 1h if I'm at work Where I have the code. The keywords are: saving callback, forceFill and array_map. But I will send you the whole code

Comment: PS: if this was the solution it would be great if you can accept the answer to display this question as answered